# how access file name with non english

Tags: java, unicode

when dealing with non-english filename.

The problem is that my program cannot gurantee those directories and filenames are in English, if some filenames using japanese, chinese character it will display some character like '?'.

anybody can suggest me wat i need to do to access non english file name

Comment: Which language and platform was that again?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You seem to be replacing the special characters, so what is the issue?

Comment: I'll be blunt here. You havent exactly clarified what your program does and where is it having trouble. Is it having trouble displaying the filenames? If so, how is it displaying the filename? Is it a Swing application or a web application using Spring, JSF, Wicket etc? From the code that you've put, I can only infer that you are attempting to prevent the "special" characters from being displayed, which should not cause problems if you are eventually dealing with ANSI or ISO-8859-1 characters.

Comment: @vijay - I agree with @Vineet.  Simply posting more code does NOT provide the kind of information we need.

Comment: What i exactly need to do is to access non english file name, my actual problem is am accessing pdf file from my outlook mail there is scheduler which runs on every 5 minutes and it checks whether is there any mail present in my mail inbox if yes then it checks is there any attachment with pdf extension, then it picks that mail and stores that pdf file in another folder, this actually working fine, problem is if that pdf file name contains any non english character schduler is not able to pick it,code i already pasted in  my previous question

Comment: What the devil is “English”?!  Do you have particular code points in mind?  There is no `\p{Script=English}` property!

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that my program cannot guarantee those directories and filenames are in English.  If a filename use japanese, chinese characters **it** will display some character like '?'.

The problem is apparently that "it" is using the wrong character set to display the filenames.  The solution depends on whether "it" is your program (via a GUI), some other application, the command shell / terminal emulator, or the user's web browser.  If you could provide more information, maybe I could offer some suggestions.

But turning the characters into underscores is most likely a bad solution.  It is liable to lead to filename clashes, and those Chinese / Japanese / etc characters are most likely meaningful to the people who created the files.

<sub>By the way, the correct term for "english" letters is Latin.</sub>

**EDIT**

For your use-case, you don't to store the PDF file using a filename that bears any relation to the supplied filename.  I suggest that you try to solve the problem by using a filename consisting of Latin numbers and letters generated from (say) `currentTimeInMillis()`.  If that fails, then your real problem has nothing to do with the filenames at all.

**EDIT 2**

You ask about the statement

```
if (fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859"))
```

This seems to be trying to unpick a filename in MIME `encoded-word` format; see [RFC 2047 Section 2](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2047.html)

Firstly, I think that code may be unnecessary.  The javadoc is not specific, but I think that the `Part.getFilename()` method *should* deal with decoding of the filename.

Second, if the decoding is necessary, then you are going about it the wrong way.  The stuff after the charset cannot simply be treated as the value of the filename.  Look at the RFC.

Third, *if you need to* you should use the relevant [`MimeUtility`](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/internet/MimeUtility.html) methods to decode "word" tokens ... like the filename.

Fourthly, ISO-8859-1 is NOT a suitable encoding for characters in non-Latin character sets.

Finally, examine the raw email headers of the emails that you are trying to decode and look for the header line that starts

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...
```

If the filename looks like "=?iso-8859-1?...", and the filename is supposed to contain japanese / chinese / etc characters, then the problem is in the client (or whatever) that constructed the email.  The character set needs to be "utf-8" or one of the other multibyte character sets.

Comment: am trying to access one pdf file which comes in my mail if this mail attached file name is with normal english it is working fine. but if it comes with non english my program is not able to read it,

Comment: public static void saveAttachments( Part part, String strFolderName )
            throws Exception
    {

        try
        {

            sFn_logFetchMailErrMsg(
                    "saveAttachments(Part part, String strFolderName): Started",
                    "INFO " );
            sFn_logFetchMailErrMsg( "The file will be downloaded to "
                    + strFolderName, "DEBUG" );

            Multipart multipart = null;
            Part subPart = null;
            String strDisposition = part.getDisposition();
            Object objContent = part.getContent();

Comment: +1, this is absolutely correct.  Java's `String` class will correctly store any Unicode characters without any special effort on the developer's part, so the only potential problem is a mismatch between the encodings of binary streams (either input or output).  @vijay, I notice that you're not paying any attention to the charset when you read the content type, which has a good chance of causing this type of problem.

Comment: What i exactly need to do is to access non english file name, my actual problem is am accessing pdf file from my outlook mail there is scheduler which runs on every 5 minutes and it checks whether is there any mail present in my mail inbox if yes then it checks is there any attachment with pdf extension, then it picks that mail and stores that pdf file in another folder, this actually working fine, problem is if that pdf file name contains any non english character schduler is not able to pick it,code i already pasted in  my previous question

Comment: *"schduler is not able to pick it"* - explain this in detail.  What do you mean by "pick"?  Is the problem with extracting the attachment from the email?  Is it with getting the filename of the attachment?  Is it with creating the file to contain the attachment?  Is it with running a command to view or process the stored PDF?  Are there any error messages?  Are there any exceptions?

Comment: sorry for bad english, 1) schduler is a java program which i was pasted code on top of this page ,this schuler run on every 5 minutes onces,schudeler responsibility is to check my mail inbox and if there is any mail with pdf file attachment, schd store that pdf file in database ,this works fine but the problem with this is, if the file name contains any non english character schdeuler only reads. "body part" of that mail "to address" "from address", it is not able to read that attachment,

Comment: one more thing can u tell me iso-8859  is ok to read unicode character, there is one loop in my function ie                     if (fileName != null) {                                            if(fileName.startsWith("=?iso-8859")) {             String strFolder = strFolderName.substring(strFolderName.lastIndexOf("/")+1,strFolderName.length());                                    fileName = strFolder + ".pdf"; } }                                                                  is this support unicode or i need to change any thing

Answer (score 2):

Java uses Unicode natively - you don't need to replace special characters, as Unicode *has* no special characters - every code point is treated equally. Your `replaceSpChars()` may be the culprit here.

Comment: my actuall problem is am accessing one pdf file which is present in my emai id, this is working fine when pdf is in english charcter.

Comment: but when that pdf comes with non english it is not reading file name itself

Comment: i have pasted exact method in this tag please check this and give me suggestion

Comment: What i exactly need to do is to access non english file name, my actual problem is am accessing pdf file from my outlook mail there is scheduler which runs on every 5 minutes and it checks whether is there any mail present in my mail inbox if yes then it checks is there any attachment with pdf extension, then it picks that mail and stores that pdf file in another folder, this actually working fine, problem is if that pdf file name contains any non english character schduler is not able to pick it,code i already pasted in  my previous question

Comment: @vijay: Is the file actually *saved* with a correct filename? It could be Outlook mangling the filename. Also, does the underlying filesystem support Unicode? (NTFS should be OK, FAT is debatable)

Comment: @Piskvor: That’s *mostly* true, excepting the despicable abomination that Java compels the programmer to think not of high-level logical Unicode characters but rather of the low-level physical UTF-16 representation, which is variable-width. It’s a grim failure of encapsulation. But I’m sure that’s not what’s afoot here.